# input and output files for simulations

Tags: python, file-io

I have to do some simulations. I am unsure how to properly handle the output and input files.

I believe the input files should use a keyword pattern, something like:

```
Parameter = 0. 0. 1. 2. ...
```

Is this a useful approach?

How do I handle this input in my code? Do I use a dictionary approach?

---

For the output, my simulations must be reproducible.

This means I should always print out:

- the input parameters; and
- the seeds used; and
- the version of my simulation code.

What is a good approach to do this?

Comment: Q: Is this a useful approach? A: If it meets your needs go for it. Q: How do I handle this input in my code? Do I use a dictionary approach? A: A dict is a completely sensible choice. If it meets your needs go for it. Q: What is a good approach to do this? A: Writing the values you want to write to your output file seems to be the best approach here. What are you actually asking? If you want my permission to do what you say you want to do then you have my permission to go ahead. If you are asking something else you will need to be a lot clearer about what you want from us.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is answerable as it stands. There are infinitely many possible formats you can use for your input and output files. There are dozens of formats with library support somewhere on the net, and something like four or five with support built in to the Python standard library. Which one you want is largely a matter of style, not something we can answer for you.

Comment: I understand the problems you pointed out. My problem is of rather general nature. I just wanted some samples, how a good approach could look like and what I need to be aware of, as this is a problem that will always reoccur.